# Who is trying to hack SFSE?

Tags: discussion, spam

There is a considerable spam posts income suddenly in SFSE it seems. Well, not sure whether they are really spams or not. They do have Japanese or Korean like letters all over the post. Anyone noticed?

Comment: FYI: a communuty bot with the name [SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/120914/smokedetector?tab=general) has also seen these posts, and stored them in a "spam database", [the data](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?site=170) clearly shows that there were 8 spam posts in the past day, while other days barely touch 1 post/day

Comment: I'd doubt it is specifically targeted at our community, flag it and we'll delete it.

Comment: Sure @SamuelDeRycke. Am also not sure whether it's targeting us or not.

Comment: It was Chinese and yes it was spam. The ones I saw today were trying to sell fake degrees and transcripts.

Comment: I also noticed and i am glad that we collectively removed

Comment: Yeah I think we got two of those last night and they were both removed within 5 minutes.

Comment: Ah, looks like more of them flooded in. 8 total. Only [one of them](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137811/%E5%8A%A0%E6%8B%BF%E5%A4%A7-%E9%98%BF%E5%8D%A1%E8%BF%AA%E4%BA%9A%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6%E6%AF%95%E4%B8%9A%E8%AF%81-qq-%E5%BE%AE%E4%BF%A1150061758%E5%8A%9E%E7%90%86%E9%98%BF%E5%8D%A1%E8%BF%AA%E4%BA%9A%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%A6%E6%AF%95%E4%B8%9A%E8%AF%81%E6%88%90%E7%BB%A9%E5%8D%95%E6%96%87%E5%87%AD%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E9%83%A8%E5%AD%A6%E5%8E%86%E8%AE%A4%E8%AF%81acadia-university-diploma) seems to not have been marked as spam.

Comment: Calling things like this 'hacking' is a pet peeve of mine. Foolishly fighting change in language usage aside, I can say from experience in administrating a large forum that 42 spam messages in a year is absurdly low. Where I came from, we were lucky if we only got 42 spam posts _in a single day_. I think this is a testament to the effectiveness of the StackExchange network's spam mitigation tactics.

Answer (score 7):

Generally spam isn't too much of a problem here. If you see something you think is spam then flag it and it'll be deleted soon enough, and frankly it rarely makes it as far as the moderators in my experience anyway. This community is fast when it comes to shutting things down that are out of place.